# How to change linewidth for symbols from plotstyle=dots in pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, scaling, plot

With the help of `plotstyle` and `dotstyle` one can realize scatterplots in pstricks. In the case one selects `plotstlye=dots` and `dotstyle` as `+`, `o`, `otimes` or similar one obtains little symbols drawed at each data position.

**My question: How can I change the linewidth of these symbols without globally scaling them?** In my case I am interested in creating thicker symbols than the default ones.

*Minimal working example:*

```
\documentclass\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[final]{pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture*}(0cm,-0.3cm)(1cm,0.3cm)  
    % some data...
    \savedata{\mydataA}[{{0.2,0}}]
    \savedata{\mydataB}[{{0.4,0}}]
    \savedata{\mydataC}[{{0.6,0}}]
    \savedata{\mydataD}[{{0.8,0}}]
    % set plotstyle and dotstyle
    \psset{plotstyle=dots, dotstyle=x} % or 'o', '+', 'otimes', ...
    % test A: simple plot -> too thin
    \dataplot{\mydataA}
    % test B: change linewidth -> only scaling, no relations are changed
    \dataplot[linewidth=3pt]{\mydataB}
    % test C: change dotscale  -> only scaling, no relations are changed
    \dataplot[dotscale=1.5]{\mydataC}
    % test D: change dotsize   -> only scaling, no relations are changed
    \dataplot[dotsize=5pt]{\mydataD}
  \end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Only scaling, no changes in the relations:

[image]

Please note: The same question can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/fXw7V5AWZ2g), but without an answer...

**[EDIT] Overview over possible solutions:**

- Using bold versions `B+`, `Bo`, `B|`, `Btriangle`, `Bsquare`, `Bpentagon` and `Basterisk`
- Most general: Defining new dotstyles (see [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/1999/000320.html) or Herbert's answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{psds@z}{%
  \pst@gdot{\pst@number\pslinewidth SLW 
    -5 -5  moveto 5 5 L -5 5 moveto 5 -5 L stroke}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(0,-0.4)(2,0.4)  
    % some data...
    \savedata{\mydataA}[{0.2,0}]
    \savedata{\mydataB}[{0.7,0}]
    \savedata{\mydataC}[{1.3,0}]
    \savedata{\mydataD}[{1.8,0}]
    % set plotstyle and dotstyle
    \psset{plotstyle=dots, dotstyle=z}% z: new dotstyle 
    \dataplot{\mydataA}
    \dataplot[linewidth=2pt]{\mydataB}
    \dataplot[dotscale=1.5,linewidth=3pt]{\mydataC}
    \dataplot[linewidth=0.5pt]{\mydataD}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since defining new dotstyles seems to be the only general answer, I will accept yours...